# Delete File having write permission in linux

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I want to create a shell script to delete all files and sub-directories having specific permissions like only write permission to all users or write and read permission.

I tried this

```
    echo "deleting files with write permission"
    for file in [find -perm -222] 
do
 rm $file
 done
   echo "FIles Deleted"
```

Comment: This is [BashPitfalls #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is off; `[` does not run a new command, it just tests whether its argument is non-empty.

`find` itself has an option to delete things it finds, so probably use that instead.

```sh
find -type f -perm -222 -print -delete
```

I'm guessing you only want regular files (`-type f`) though `-delete` can handle directories, too.  The `-print` causes the files to be printed before being deleted.

(Actually your syntax simply loops over the tokens `[find`, `-perm`, and `-222]`; the arguments to `for` are just strings. If you wanted to run a command there the syntax would be `for file in $(command ...)` but this is bad practice too because it will break if `command` outputs a file name which is not a single token.)

Comment: Thank you this works fine, but can you add a comment for deleting files having to write permission to groups.

Comment: Do you mean "having *no* write permission"? That would be `-perm -202`.

Comment: @tripleee : What you say is correct, but does not really target the problem here. First of all, the OP did not use `[  find  ]`, but `[find`, so if there were a command to be executed, it would be the latter, not `[`.  Further, he uses the odd `[find` after a `for .... in`, and in this case `[find ...]` is not a command to be executed, but  just an odd wildcard pattern for a single-character filename.